# After updating manjaro-system-20210412-1, mysqld.sock is deleted after the system restarts

Tags: mysql, linux, manjaro

After I updated manjaro-system-20210412-1 and restarted it, I found that mysqlserver failed to start

```
➜  ~ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
➜  ~ systemctl status mysqld.service         
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-20 15:42:18 CST; 23s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 877 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 923 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 923 (code=exited, status=127)

4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, 
code=exited, status=127/n/a
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit- 
code'.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, 
restart counter is at 5.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Start request repeated too 
quickly.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit- 
code'.
4月 20 15:42:18 ybybwdwd-vmwarevirtualplatform systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
➜  ~ systemctl restart mysqld.service 
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I found that the files in the /run/mysqld/ directory disappeared. I can't search with sudo find / -name'mysqld.sock'.

I used sudo pacman -Rns mysql to uninstall mysql and reinstall it still reported the above error.

The mysql version is 8.0.23, installed with pacman.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I can't search with sudo find / -name'mysqld.sock'"? It returns nothing?
What did systemctl and journalctl say? Did you start the MySQL server before attempting to connect? Are you sure it was already running?

Comment: Yeah,it returns nothing.MySQL server cannot start.And the return of systemctl has been given above